# Keycloak add user from custom user provider

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-spi

I'm creating a custom user storage using the [User storage SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#add-remove-user-and-query-capability-interfaces)

My problem here is that that addUser function is not called.
When i try to add a user, the function `getUserByNickName` is directly called but do not find any user.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The solution for me was that the getUserByUsername had to throw an error for addUser to be called. So in my case if I returned a 404 from my API if user is not found then addUser was called.